# How to download logs from GAE Java App logs now that appcfg is shut down

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I used to use appcfg.cmd to download the GAE java standard instance logs without any issues until start of April 2023. However it is now erroring out. On doing some research, it looks like Google shut down this functionality and wants us to use gcloud, but then

gcloud app log commands does not support downloading logs. I tried to read the logs and pipe it to a text file, however the read does not bring any application logs written using log4j log statements. How do I download the logs as they provide information about the downloads activity of the application which is critical information for us.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/tools/downloading-logs#requesting_the_logs) and you mentioned in the question that `gcloud app log commands does not support downloading logs`.

> The appcfg tool is now shut down. The replacement, Google Cloud CLI, does not support the ability to download logs; however, you can view your logs using the `gcloud app log` commands.

Right now there is no option to download logs. But you can view the logs by using the command [`gcloud app log`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs). Please feel free to raise [Feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) for the same.

Comment: Even the view logs does not bring the app logs. is there a way to view the logs sent by the application.

Comment: Can you try with this [`gcloud app logs tail`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/tail) and also check with this [Viewing logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/writing-application-logs?tab=java#viewing_logs).

Comment: Even the tail option does not provide the logs created by the application.

Comment: Can you try checking with [Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/writing-application-logs?tab=java#viewing_logs) to view logs written by apps running in the standard environment. Also check this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/logs#reading_logs_in_the_console).

Comment: They are available in the Logs Explorer. They are not available in the gcloud read logs or tail though

Comment: It seems like it requires internal support to find the cause. Feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).